# Separate input jacks as independent input devices

Tags: laptop, audio, drivers, audio-recording, realtek-hd-audio

So I have a pair of earbuds which I have been using for about 3 years now, they are still working (the output part, at least) and I use them daily for my laptop, however, their microphone recently stopped working, so I wanted to use my laptop's internal mic for input, while still using my earbuds for output. However for some reason my sound settings refuse to recognize the earbuds as a separate device, and instead show "Microphone Array" as an input device, so either I disconnect my earbuds to be able to input sound at all, or I have to live without input. I don't know why I can't separate these inputs, I looked for and tried everything, My Realtek Audio Console does not contain a setting to separate the inputs, and neither do my Windows settings. I am at my wit's end here as I have tried everything to no avail, I thought about editing a registry key to forcibly enable separation of devices, but I have no idea which key to edit. So if anyone has any idea how to do that, or any other solution for that matter, I would really appreciate the help.

**Please note** that I did try using the default Microsoft audio driver and it did work to solve my problem, although it gave rise to new issues as the audio processed with that driver sounds absolutely horrendous, plus the input is loud, and the sounds of my typing on the keyboard are vividly heard on the other end, making it very impractical for output or input. So if possible, I would love to find another solution.

[Here is a screenshot of what my sound device settings looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAkRw.png)

**Device Specs:**

- Manufacturer: Lenovo
- Laptop Model: Legion Y540
- OS: Windows 11
- Motherboard: LNVNB161216
- Realtek Audio Driver Version: 6.0.8921.1
- CPU: Intel Core i7 9750H
- Installed RAM: 16 GB
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the other disabled device in your picture the internal mic? Enable that.

Comment: That device is the stereo mix. It has nothing to do with the mic, I already tried it and its only function is to help record the sound outputting to speakers when recording a video (such as music playing on the laptop).